# Global Resource Issue in MonoDevelop Xamarin Studio

Tags: c#, asp.net, mono, monodevelop, xamarin-studio

The following code:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" Text="<%$Resources:Main, Save %>" />
```

is producing the following error:

```
Error: Unexpected '<' in tag 'asp:Button'.
```

Details:

```
ASP.net 4.0 Web Application (C#)
Xamarin Studio Version 4.0.12 (build 3
```

Is there a workaround for this issue?

Edit:

Will mono framework parse the resource if the solution was compiled by Visual Studio targeting "Mono 2.8 Profile"?

Answer (score 2):

Nope, you can't even use single quotes like you can in Visual Studio to get away with code like that. You're going to have to use code-behind to accomplish what you are trying. Sorry

To answer your edit, your syntax is valid. The problem is with Monodevelop not Mono. Nothing in the C# spec states that what you are doing is wrong, this is a parser issue with quotes and brackets in a specific tool.

The implicit syntax should work in its stead:

`<asp:Button runat="server" Text="DefaultText" meta:resourcekey="Save" />`

More reading: [ASP.NET Web Page Resources Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227427.aspx)

Comment: So will the mono framework support the use of resource like it's done here if the code was compiled by Visual Studio?

Comment: Not if recompiling also means recompiling the code on this page as well. The problem isn't with your code, its with the syntax. If you have that code in your project and you try to compile it will give you that error. The fact it works in studio lets you know your code is sound, monodevelop is a little more strict on the syntax as Microsoft understands us hacky web developers a little better :)

Comment: Now your idea can totally work if you want to have the whole page get it's bits from another dll, thats possible. Compile another web application and upload them both to the same website. You could also create a localization project that wraps your webcontrols and pre-sets the text before it's used on the page if you require bits from one project on a page and bits from another (ie, these localized strings and say data for a report or repeater)

Comment: Could you please edit your answer and post an alternative solution on how to do things the "right way". I am now targeting "Mono 2.8 Profile" from Visual Studio.

Comment: I've added a little more help to my answer, without knowing what tool you are compiling in I can't really answer you much more than this. If you are using Studio, keep using the explicit syntax, if you are not try the implicit syntax I've suggested. Combined with that article I'm sure can resolve this.